# Matplotlib not showing characters of different languages (Hindi) and other characters like emojis

Tags: python, matplotlib, unicode, fonts, data-visualization

The function simply takes data of some videos and try to represent them in a horizontal stacked bar chart. The parameter data is a dictionary of lists `{'key' : [ ], 'key2' : [ ].....}`. Sample data (data for the result in the image) is given below. The problem arising is that it is not able to represent the data that has Hindi characters and emojis in it (see the y-axis). The problem may be because of the Unicode set of the font. I tried changing the font of yticks but nothing is working.

## Python Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def HorizontalBar(data):
    category_names = ['Views', 'Likes', 'Dislikes', 'Comments']
    labels = list(data.keys())
    data = np.array(list(data.values()))
    data_cum = data.cumsum(axis=1)
    category_colors=['lightblue','#00ff00','#ff4d4d', 'yellow']
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 15))
    ax.invert_yaxis()
    ax.set_xlim(0, np.sum(data, axis=1).max())
    for i, (colname, color) in enumerate(zip(category_names, category_colors)):
        widths = data[:, i]
        starts = data_cum[:, i] - widths
        ax.barh(labels,
                widths,
                left=starts,
                height=0.5,
                label=colname,
                color=color
                )
        xcenters = starts + widths / 2

        for y, (x, c) in enumerate(zip(xcenters, widths)):
            if int(c) != 0:
                ax.text(x, y, str("%.2f" % c),
                        ha='center', va='center',
                        color='k', size="x-small")
    ax.legend(ncol=len(category_names))

    plt.show()
```

[image]

## Sample data

```
data={'Explore the Universe and Planets Documentary - In Search of Alien Planets in the Universe': [4.585889172397744, 2.4409090820652177, 1.6127838567197355, 0], 'Jumping From Space! - Red Bull Space Dive - BBC': [7.81020184066208, 6.029907456385649, 4.577514777773365, 4.973788033599711], 'WATCH NASA: Earth Viewing cameras - Earth From Space ISS feed #RealTimeTracker': [7.322351362215814, 5.5248075007512005, 4.199782593968985, 0], 'अंतरिक्ष के 20 Facts जो आपको किताबों में नहीं मिलेंगे 20 Space Facts You Won’t Find in Textbooks': [6.267141913650333, 4.71803642078278, 3.273464272621346, 3.2022157758011316], 'How they Eat, Drink and survive in Space ׃ Sunita Williams in The International Space Station': [6.110854582811279, 4.061716293159897, 2.8068580295188172, 2.8943160626844384], 'ब्रम्हांड और जीवन की कहानी | Universe , Space and Life Documentary in Hindi - 4K': [5.30875857554719, 3.739255803268511, 2.346352974450639, 2.429752280002408], 'Story of Man Who Fell From Space!': [6.651851911542932, 4.956221272827951, 3.6338722626583326, 4.043755126968679], 'JOURNEY TO THE EDGE OF THE Universe | Space Documentary 2020 Full HD 1080p': [5.614046768959247, 3.592398846115564, 2.4771212547196626, 2.8356905714924254], '10 INSANE Space Discoveries 2020': [4.678163150262343, 2.9258275746247424, 1.6532125137753437, 2.130333768495006], 'What Happened to Lost Women in Space?': [6.785011401802075, 4.7992922918301195, 3.7758288144646124, 4.032779879191245], 'ISS - International Space Station - Inside ISS - Tour - Q&A - HD': [6.04289786529016, 4.082534052872713, 2.60422605308447, 3.251638220448212], '10 Terrifying Facts About Space': [6.188611290819635, 4.34966598409663, 2.9628426812012423, 3.4448251995097476], 'The Discovery of the Universe Documentary - Planets of our Solar System': [3.384353414137506, 2.24551266781415, 1.5440680443502757, 0], 'I Went To SPACE In GTA 5.. (GTA 5 Mods)': [6.123185320714601, 4.776505053570831, 2.9916690073799486, 3.485295438726089], 'A Mysterious Journey to the End of Space': [5.731390507617008, 0, 0, 3.2430380486862944], 'Honey in space': [7.417521845922459, 5.709508248618531, 3.918344928962275, 4.468022226494091], 'WHAT IS THE EVERYDAY LIFE OF AN ASTRONAUT IN SPACE LIKE?': [6.803599467158072, 4.530276557681542, 3.255272505103306, 3.6644539285811577], "In 2009 Something Happened In This Region Of Space That NASA Scientists Can't Explain": [4.18261434773635, 2.9951962915971793, 1.7558748556724915, 2.103803720955957], 'The Search for Life in Space Documentary - Where is the Centre of the Universe': [4.259402728142589, 2.2329961103921536, 1.255272505103306, 0], 'The Milky Way Galaxy Planets | Space Documentary 2020 Full HD 1080p': [5.701836422125923, 3.5258219521566625, 2.705007959333336, 2.6190933306267428], "The World's Biggest Skyscrapers (Some Will Even Reach Space!)": [5.146630285904248, 0, 0, 2.885361220031512], 'Why There Is Light on Earth But Not in Space': [6.276289660766413, 4.5772159697346515, 3.119585774961784, 3.447623097760286], "Spacewalk to Upgrade Space Station's Power System": [5.486618892027429, 4.018201022496291, 2.346352974450639, 2.315970345456918], 'What Happened to Felicette in Space? *First Cat in Space*': [5.801479173275887, 4.116508123737346, 2.932473764677153, 3.705949194910296], 'What If You Were the Last Human and Trapped in Space?': [5.7236830219147246, 4.179523067035285, 2.5622928644564746, 3.209783014848515], '10 Scary Yet Beautiful Facts About Space & Us': [7.303539813426686, 5.52070226250271, 4.194764024110887, 4.712977823472636], '15 STRANGEST Things Caught From Space!': [5.478580923742277, 3.7083359026822635, 2.584331224367531, 2.5538830266438746], 'What Happened to Ham in Space? *Sad Story of Ham*': [7.086435398459355, 5.265023120238883, 3.8825245379548803, 4.456745495347945], 'What Happened to the People Lost in Space?': [6.285491597306807, 4.41806916354166, 3.131297796597623, 3.210318519826232], 'My Space - Don Omar ft. Wisin y Yandel': [7.925400999293699, 5.399019191395705, 4.107142105833073, 3.734559821579476], '15 Space saving furniture ideas for your home Live Smart & Expand Your Space': [7.516409324272038, 5.195096710611856, 4.228400358703005, 3.641077313325374], 'I Found A STAIRWAY To SPACE In GTA 5.. (GTA 5 Mods)': [6.2833840081994925, 5.104657791008797, 3.318272080211627, 3.6464037262230695], 'is Space Shuttle Aluminum Bulletproo ? ✈️': [5.326947948497112, 4.2316989107643925, 2.4983105537896004, 3.0827853703164503], 'Russia ने किया Space में हतियार Test': [4.13510083376572, 3.097604328874411, 1.4913616938342726, 1.7558748556724915], "The View from Space - Earth's Countries and Coastlines": [7.086502021039129, 4.63181904831605, 4.299572666758495, 4.092896010921856], 'What Will You Look Like in 4th Dimensional Space': [5.273542933650583, 3.734319680859007, 2.2576785748691846, 2.9537596917332287], 'StoryBots Outer Space | Planets, Sun, Moon, Earth and Stars | Solar System Super Song | Fun Learning': [7.578386260048627, 4.983797626014332, 4.229041573173397, 2.7024305364455254], 'I Wanna Be An Astronaut! | A Space Song |  Little Angel Kids Songs': [7.502222939931596, 5.105847270810036, 4.874133778827972, 0], 'Dove Cameron, Sofia Carson - Space Between (from Descendants 2) (Official Video)': [7.797358061362572, 5.722391209132822, 4.12251077061032, 4.256549382152194], 'NEWS: UK and US say Russia Fired A Satellite Weapon In Space | G I Joe Movie |': [4.104828403653656, 3.144262773761991, 1.3424226808222062, 2.0453229787866576], '10 Most MYSTERIOUS Photos Ever Taken From Space': [5.959342907535137, 3.7247672456463103, 2.7403626894942437, 2.7315887651867388], 'Planet Earth seen from space (Full HD 1080p) ORIGINAL': [7.39847202348151, 4.9780891730561425, 3.8489892062511672, 4.2499806059095295], 'Unbelievably Strange Planets in Space': [6.988510530789991, 5.113445298538364, 4.139753185695353, 4.2003579455416356], 'Spacewalk Outside the International Space Station': [5.685139577231512, 4.199618067707931, 2.4533183400470375, 2.7558748556724915], '15 FUTURE Space Station Design Concepts': [3.789439684567179, 2.4183012913197452, 1.0791812460476249, 1.462397997898956], 'A Record-Tying Spacewalk to Upgrade the Space Station on This Week @NASA – July 24, 2020': [4.650336669434548, 3.396896449142524, 1.6989700043360187, 0], 'SpaceX astronauts speak to Yahoo Finance from International Space Station': [3.918764031027999, 1.6720978579357175, 1.0791812460476249, 1.0], 'What If You Shoot a Gun in Space?': [5.8650020545642425, 4.24206911233894, 2.7701152947871015, 3.159266331093494], "The Magnetic Universe — it's Electric! | Space News": [3.9586594270529334, 3.0916669575956846, 1.146128035678238, 2.3654879848909], 'Teen Titans Go! | Space Adventures! | DC Kids': [7.184527134243162, 4.79228660554035, 4.018284308426531, 0]}
```

Comment: Sorry Sarthak, neither @Gustav or myself had any luck with getting emojis into the tick labels.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney & Gustav, thank you for your efforts and inputs, will keep you posted if something advances :)

Comment: There are two separate issues: 1) you either need to use a synthetic font or generate a new font from appropriate subsetted fonts, a non-trivial task; 2) you require opentype rendering, which the default backends for matplotlib do not support. Best option is to install mplcairo and all its dependencies and use that as the backend for matplotlib.

Answer (score 3):

- Alternate option using Pandas
- Specify a TrueType font and then set the [`FontProperties`](https://matplotlib.org/api/font_manager_api.html?highlight=fontproperties#matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties).

  - *A font may be specified using the absolute path to a font file, by using the `fname` kwarg. However, in this case, it is typically simpler to just pass the path (as a [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path), not a `str`) to the `font` kwarg of the [Text](https://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) object.*
- Basically, in order to display a particular type of font as the figure tick labels, matplotlib must be configured to use the correct font type.

  - [How I got Matplotlib to plot Apple Color Emojis](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-i-got-matplotlib-to-plot-apple-color-emojis-c983767b39e0) suggests setting a matplotlib backend that supports TrueType collections (ttc).
- Using `data` from the OP
- Interestingly, if you look at the column names of `df`, the Hindi characters and emojis display correctly.
- Also, if you look at the list `text`, all the characters are properly displayed.
- I can't get the emojis to properly display on the plot figure.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pathlib import Path
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties

# point to the font location with an absolute path
nirm = Path('c:/Windows/Fonts/Nirmala.ttf')

# configure the Hindi font
hindi_font = FontProperties(fname=nirm)

# create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['Views', 'Likes', 'Dislikes', 'Comments'])

# pandas.DataFrame.plot uses the index for the axis so Transpose df and then plot
ax = df.T.plot.barh(stacked=True, figsize=(10, 14))

# get the y tick labels
text = [item.get_text() for item in ax.get_yticklabels()]

# set the labels with the ttf
ax.set_yticklabels(text, fontproperties=hindi_font)

# annotate the bars
for rect in ax.patches:
    # Find where everything is located
    height = rect.get_height()
    width = rect.get_width()
    x = rect.get_x()
    y = rect.get_y()

    # The width of the bar is the count value and can used as the label
    label_text = f'{width:.02f}'

    label_x = x + width / 2
    label_y = y + height / 2

    # don't include label if it's equivalently 0
    if width > 0.001:
        ax.text(label_x, label_y, label_text, ha='center', va='center', fontsize=8)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Render Hindi characters as follows:
First run the Linux command `fc-list :lang=hi family` (see https://linux.die.net/man/1/fc-list) to generate the complete list of Hindi fonts, and from there select `Arial Unicode MS`.

[image]

Add this to the matplotlib font parameter, together with 2 others:

```
mpl.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['Source Han Sans TW',
                                   'sans-serif',
                                   'Arial Unicode MS'  # fc-list :lang=hi family
                                   ]
```

Next, translate emojis to text with the `emojis` package which can be installed from `pypi` (use command: `pip install emojis`):

```
import emojis

labels = list(data.keys())
labels_decoded = [emojis.decode(label) for label in labels]
```

This produces text description of emojis instead of their graphical representations (e.g. `:airplane:`).
For a graphical representation, you could try using https://github.com/matplotlib/mplcairo

Complete program:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

import emojis

data = {'Explore the Universe and Planets Documentary - In Search of Alien Planets in the Universe': [4.585889172397744, 2.4409090820652177, 1.6127838567197355, 0], 'Jumping From Space! - Red Bull Space Dive - BBC': [7.81020184066208, 6.029907456385649, 4.577514777773365, 4.973788033599711], 'WATCH NASA: Earth Viewing cameras - Earth From Space ISS feed #RealTimeTracker': [7.322351362215814, 5.5248075007512005, 4.199782593968985, 0], 'अंतरिक्ष के 20 Facts जो आपको किताबों में नहीं मिलेंगे 20 Space Facts You Won’t Find in Textbooks': [6.267141913650333, 4.71803642078278, 3.273464272621346, 3.2022157758011316], 'How they Eat, Drink and survive in Space ׃ Sunita Williams in The International Space Station': [6.110854582811279, 4.061716293159897, 2.8068580295188172, 2.8943160626844384], 'ब्रम्हांड और जीवन की कहानी | Universe , Space and Life Documentary in Hindi - 4K': [5.30875857554719, 3.739255803268511, 2.346352974450639, 2.429752280002408], 'Story of Man Who Fell From Space!': [6.651851911542932, 4.956221272827951, 3.6338722626583326, 4.043755126968679], 'JOURNEY TO THE EDGE OF THE Universe | Space Documentary 2020 Full HD 1080p': [5.614046768959247, 3.592398846115564, 2.4771212547196626, 2.8356905714924254], '10 INSANE Space Discoveries 2020': [4.678163150262343, 2.9258275746247424, 1.6532125137753437, 2.130333768495006], 'What Happened to Lost Women in Space?': [6.785011401802075, 4.7992922918301195, 3.7758288144646124, 4.032779879191245], 'ISS - International Space Station - Inside ISS - Tour - Q&A - HD': [6.04289786529016, 4.082534052872713, 2.60422605308447, 3.251638220448212], '10 Terrifying Facts About Space': [6.188611290819635, 4.34966598409663, 2.9628426812012423, 3.4448251995097476], 'The Discovery of the Universe Documentary - Planets of our Solar System': [3.384353414137506, 2.24551266781415, 1.5440680443502757, 0], 'I Went To SPACE In GTA 5.. (GTA 5 Mods)': [6.123185320714601, 4.776505053570831, 2.9916690073799486, 3.485295438726089], 'A Mysterious Journey to the End of Space': [5.731390507617008, 0, 0, 3.2430380486862944], 'Honey in space': [7.417521845922459, 5.709508248618531, 3.918344928962275, 4.468022226494091], 'WHAT IS THE EVERYDAY LIFE OF AN ASTRONAUT IN SPACE LIKE?': [6.803599467158072, 4.530276557681542, 3.255272505103306, 3.6644539285811577], "In 2009 Something Happened In This Region Of Space That NASA Scientists Can't Explain": [4.18261434773635, 2.9951962915971793, 1.7558748556724915, 2.103803720955957], 'The Search for Life in Space Documentary - Where is the Centre of the Universe': [4.259402728142589, 2.2329961103921536, 1.255272505103306, 0], 'The Milky Way Galaxy Planets | Space Documentary 2020 Full HD 1080p': [5.701836422125923, 3.5258219521566625, 2.705007959333336, 2.6190933306267428], "The World's Biggest Skyscrapers (Some Will Even Reach Space!)": [5.146630285904248, 0, 0, 2.885361220031512], 'Why There Is Light on Earth But Not in Space': [6.276289660766413, 4.5772159697346515, 3.119585774961784, 3.447623097760286], "Spacewalk to Upgrade Space Station's Power System": [5.486618892027429, 4.018201022496291, 2.346352974450639, 2.315970345456918], 'What Happened to Felicette in Space? *First Cat in Space*': [5.801479173275887, 4.116508123737346, 2.932473764677153, 3.705949194910296], 'What If You Were the Last Human and Trapped in Space?': [5.7236830219147246, 4.179523067035285, 2.5622928644564746, 3.209783014848515], '10 Scary Yet Beautiful Facts About Space & Us': [7.303539813426686, 5.52070226250271, 4.194764024110887, 4.712977823472636], '15 STRANGEST Things Caught From Space!': [5.478580923742277, 3.7083359026822635, 2.584331224367531, 2.5538830266438746], 'What Happened to Ham in Space? *Sad Story of Ham*': [7.086435398459355, 5.265023120238883, 3.8825245379548803, 4.456745495347945], 'What Happened to the People Lost in Space?': [6.285491597306807, 4.41806916354166, 3.131297796597623, 3.210318519826232], 'My Space - Don Omar ft. Wisin y Yandel': [7.925400999293699, 5.399019191395705, 4.107142105833073, 3.734559821579476], '15 Space saving furniture ideas for your home Live Smart & Expand Your Space': [7.516409324272038, 5.195096710611856, 4.228400358703005, 3.641077313325374], 'I Found A STAIRWAY To SPACE In GTA 5.. (GTA 5 Mods)': [6.2833840081994925, 5.104657791008797, 3.318272080211627, 3.6464037262230695], 'is Space Shuttle Aluminum Bulletproo ? ✈️': [5.326947948497112, 4.2316989107643925, 2.4983105537896004, 3.0827853703164503], 'Russia ने किया Space में हतियार Test': [4.13510083376572, 3.097604328874411, 1.4913616938342726, 1.7558748556724915], "The View from Space - Earth's Countries and Coastlines": [7.086502021039129, 4.63181904831605, 4.299572666758495, 4.092896010921856], 'What Will You Look Like in 4th Dimensional Space': [5.273542933650583, 3.734319680859007, 2.2576785748691846, 2.9537596917332287], 'StoryBots Outer Space | Planets, Sun, Moon, Earth and Stars | Solar System Super Song | Fun Learning': [7.578386260048627, 4.983797626014332, 4.229041573173397, 2.7024305364455254], 'I Wanna Be An Astronaut! | A Space Song |  Little Angel Kids Songs': [7.502222939931596, 5.105847270810036, 4.874133778827972, 0], 'Dove Cameron, Sofia Carson - Space Between (from Descendants 2) (Official Video)': [7.797358061362572, 5.722391209132822, 4.12251077061032, 4.256549382152194], 'NEWS: UK and US say Russia Fired A Satellite Weapon In Space | G I Joe Movie |': [4.104828403653656, 3.144262773761991, 1.3424226808222062, 2.0453229787866576], '10 Most MYSTERIOUS Photos Ever Taken From Space': [5.959342907535137, 3.7247672456463103, 2.7403626894942437, 2.7315887651867388], 'Planet Earth seen from space (Full HD 1080p) ORIGINAL': [7.39847202348151, 4.9780891730561425, 3.8489892062511672, 4.2499806059095295], 'Unbelievably Strange Planets in Space': [6.988510530789991, 5.113445298538364, 4.139753185695353, 4.2003579455416356], 'Spacewalk Outside the International Space Station': [5.685139577231512, 4.199618067707931, 2.4533183400470375, 2.7558748556724915], '15 FUTURE Space Station Design Concepts': [3.789439684567179, 2.4183012913197452, 1.0791812460476249, 1.462397997898956], 'A Record-Tying Spacewalk to Upgrade the Space Station on This Week @NASA – July 24, 2020': [4.650336669434548, 3.396896449142524, 1.6989700043360187, 0], 'SpaceX astronauts speak to Yahoo Finance from International Space Station': [3.918764031027999, 1.6720978579357175, 1.0791812460476249, 1.0], 'What If You Shoot a Gun in Space?': [5.8650020545642425, 4.24206911233894, 2.7701152947871015, 3.159266331093494], "The Magnetic Universe — it's Electric! | Space News": [3.9586594270529334, 3.0916669575956846, 1.146128035678238, 2.3654879848909], 'Teen Titans Go! | Space Adventures! | DC Kids': [7.184527134243162, 4.79228660554035, 4.018284308426531, 0]}

category_names = ['Views', 'Likes', 'Dislikes', 'Comments']

labels = list(data.keys())
labels_decoded = [emojis.decode(label) for label in labels]

data = np.array(list(data.values()))
data_cum = data.cumsum(axis=1)
category_colors = ['b', 'r', 'g', 'y']

mpl.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['Source Han Sans TW',
                                   'sans-serif',
                                   "Arial Unicode MS"  # fc-list :lang=hi family
                                   ]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 15))
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.set_xlim(0, np.sum(data, axis=1).max())

for i, (colname, color) in enumerate(zip(category_names, category_colors)):
    widths = data[:, i]
    starts = data_cum[:, i] - widths

    ax.barh(labels_decoded,
            widths,
            left=starts,
            height=0.5,
            label=colname,
            color=color
            )

    xcenters = starts + widths / 2
    for y, (x, c) in enumerate(zip(xcenters, widths)):
        if int(c) != 0:
            ax.text(x, y, str("%.2f" % c), ha='center', va='center',
                    color='k', size="x-small")
ax.legend(ncol=len(category_names))
plt.show()
```

Returns the plot:
[image]

Comment: This does seem to get the Hindi, but not the Emojis `is Space Shuttle Aluminum Bulletproo ? ✈️`

Comment: You are right, I changed the emojis to text instead, as their graphics didn’t render in Matplotlib.

Comment: What's interesting is if I use `ticks, labels = plt.yticks()`, `labels = list(labels)` & `text = [l.get_text() for l in labels]`, `text` has all the correct characters, they just don't display properly in the figure.

Comment: Do you suppose it could be a matter of updating the correct fonts ?

Comment: I'm posting an alternate solution that points specifically to the hindi ttf on windows, but I also can't get the emoji to display in the figure. Though, it does display in the dataframe column header and in the text list.

Comment: Sounds good. I am quite curious to see how the emojis can be solved in a matplotlib figure.

Comment: I wasn't able to find a good solution for displaying emojis. Different ttf packages seem to convert different emojis. I was able to find one ttf that would convert the airplane (though not with the detail), but I couldn't find a ttf for the rocket. I spent several hours trying. /shrug

Comment: I also had luck with the airplane by using Apples font. Also without details. I really like your idea of using pandas, that made the axis labels much more readable.

Comment: I'm on windows, so Apple Color Emoji.ttc wouldn't work for me

Comment: I know some "purists" get bent about using Pandas or answerd with Pandas, but it makes so many things a lot easier.

Comment: I agree, Pandas really makes life easier :)

Answer (score 1):

**You can use font_manager in matplotlib to use any font you want.
Here is an example code:--**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
fontpath = './HindiFonts/Akshar Unicode.ttf'
prop = fm.FontProperties(fname=fontpath)
plt.imshow(X_train[0])
plt.title(y_train[0], fontproperties=prop)
plt.show()
```

**I am sharing an example of with and without font_manager**
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPVne.png)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzgSo.png)